# PC cannot route via specific router, regardless of OS

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to narrow in on why one specific PC I have cannot connect to the Internet, *nor even ping the router* it is connected to, but is fine on other networks, and other devices are fine on the router.

It is specifically this PC with this router, as far as I can tell.

**It had been working previously**, I cannot tell what has changed - as far as I know, nothing.

### Problem

- PC is dual-boot Windows and Linux.
- Under Linux, the wifi connection to the BT Router shows as 84% strength, and it gets an IP via DHCP (confirmed by checking from another laptop)
- Under Windows, the network connection also is strong from the wifi point of view, but shows "No Internet"
- Under both OSes, pinging the router's IP itself results in 100% packet loss `*`
- From other laptops, pinging the router returns pings and 0% packet loss
- I can connect this same problem PC to my phone's wifi hotspot and it connects and routes fine, can ping 8.8.8.8 without issue

### Attempted further troubleshooting

- Tried flushing DNS and network cache in Windows, no effect
- Under Linux and Windows, tried using a static IP with the expected configuration (router IP, DNS mask, IP on correct subnet, chosen static IP known to be unused), matched against a working laptop - no effect, still cannot ping router
- tried moving router closer to desktop PC, no effect (really does not seem to be a signal thing)
- ensured router was not configured to block any devices
- restarted the router
- reset router to factory defaults, tried using default SSID and password

`*` Sometimes it is between 70% and 100%, more frequently 100% loss. I sometimes also get a lot of duplicate packets back - one attempt recently gave me:

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 2 received, +65 duplicates, 80% packet loss, time 9236ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 852.490/1313.819/2760.262/301.680 ms, pipe 3
```

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this would be helpful, either Windows or Linux commands ; any suggestions on what configurations to look at/read up on welcome.

I don't have the cabling to test ethernet to the router from the desktop at the moment.

### Update

It seems the netwokring does work for a few seconds after joining the router (successful pings), and then after a bit, it starts failing again. I mistakenly thought LiveUSB was working *but it isn't* - rather, it is presenting the same symptoms as the installed OS, that is, for a few seconds networking is fine.... and then it starts failing.

Not the case with my tether.

Comment: Can your router be configured to deny connection to specific MAC addresses? If so, check to see if the problem laptop's MAC address has been (inadvertently?) denied.

Comment: Already checked that, it is not set up to deny anything.

Comment: Guess: Something goes wrong with the combination of your PCs Wifi hardware and your routers Wifi hardware. Try `iw phy and `iw dev wlan0 scan dump` as root to see which capabilities your Wifi hardware claims to support, and which capabilities the router claims to support, possibly one of those doesn't work correctly. Also compare with other PCs (if running Linux) for which the router works.

Comment: Can the problem computer connect to other wifi networks (e.g., public hotspots at McDonald's or Starbuck's)?

Comment: Yes it can, my phone wifi hotspot works fine for it

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple laptops. Can they ping each other?

Comment: The only difference between the device not working on your network and working on others is the router - something in the router's config for your laptop's IP and/or MAC is misconfigured - it's an either/or scenario and the only place the problem could be is within the router's config for that specific device and it's easy to verify this: in your router's WebUI, create a settings/config backup then reset your router to it's factory defaults.

Comment: I can ping work Windows laptop with Linux laptop, the other way round fails but I'm pretty sure that's Windows blocking ICMP requests, even if I seem to have turned that on. Not Windows-savvy enough to know... But those are not the issue. Main problem is on a desktop PC, no laptops involved

Comment: I did a reset to factory defaults a few days ago (I should update my description), to no avail... even with full defaults, including leaving the default SSID and password, still same behaviour....

Comment: Ah, I misread the question: Basically my question is whether the computer in question can successfully communicate with other devices on the local network, like your laptops or maybe a NAS or the like.

Comment: @DanielB No, it cannot. It successfully gets an IP from the router, but any attempts to route via it fail after a few seconds of being on that wifi: no pinging Internet, no pinging devices on the subnet, no pinging the router even.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have wifi drivers installed in windows?
See here:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-check-device-driver-version-windows-10

Comment: It used to work fine and, yes, I had indeed installed the wifi drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tried a new static IP, try a new MAC.

On Windows, go to Device Manager, find your network card, go into its Properties, and in the Advanced tab change the value of Network Address.

On Linux you may try one of those methods: https://ostechnix.com/change-mac-address-linux/

Comment: Finally gotten round to this. Alas, did not help. Changed MAC, restarted networking, received new address, but still same symptoms....